# de duplicating access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a very large table called runners which has about 50,00 instances of duplication and I want to remove the duplicates.
After some experimentation I got a query working that highlights the duplicates.

Then I tried to set a new field called 'del' to true so I can then delete with confidence.I tried a join with the successful query but I am getting an error message "Error in Update syntax" and rests on "UPDATE"

My sql looks like this:

```
`Update History A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Max(History.rDate) AS lastRun, History.Runner, History.rtime, History.source, Count(History.rdate) AS occurrs, History.rDate, History.audittime
FROM History
GROUP BY History.Runner, History.rtime, History.source, History.rDate, History.audittime
HAVING (((Count(1))>1)) 
)B

SET A.del =-1 
ON (( A.rdate =B.rdate) AND (A.Runner =B.runner))
WHERE  A.audittime < B.audittime 
;`
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be a great help.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you aggregate and group by the same column: `rDate`? Also, is `rDate` not a datetime, so what is `rtime`? And `audittime`?

Comment: Doesn't the `on` clause have to come before the `set`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a direct `DELETE` statement using a correlated subquery. Not quite sure of your data but below removes the highest *rdate* field among the *Runner* and *Source* groupings (as these two fields seems like the only identifiers other than datetimes).

```
DELETE 
FROM History main
WHERE main.rDate IN 
   (SELECT Max(h.rDate) AS lastRun
    FROM History h
    WHERE h.Runner = main.Runner AND h.source = main.source           
    HAVING Count(1) > 1)
```

Now, if there are more than 2 duplicates, you may need to run this query again and again until no changes are made. Alternatively, run the following `DELETE` which keeps only the minimum *rDate*:

```
DELETE 
FROM History main
WHERE NOT main.rDate IN 
   (SELECT Min(h.rDate) AS lastRun
    FROM History h
    WHERE h.Runner = main.Runner AND h.source = main.source)
AND 
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM History h
    WHERE h.Runner = main.Runner AND h.source = main.source) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
to Parfait. yes the query looks a bit messy., I needed to visually veriy I was getting the right data:
A simpler version is:

Comment: @ Parfait. yes the query looks a bit messy., I needed to visually veriy I was getting the right data:
A simpler version is: 
SELECT Max(History.rDate) AS lastRun, History.Runner,  Count(History.rdate) AS occurrs,History.audittime
FROM History
GROUP BY History.Runner,History.audittime
HAVING (((Count(1))>1)) 

I am struggling with the other suggestions

Comment: auditime is a timedate that tells me the precise time a record was added. It is useful to keep the last one for example.
During debugging, dupes had to be allowed, now they need to be removed.
I dont want two records with the same rdate (probabaly needs to be same rdate and rtime) but keep it simple for now

Comment: I cant get top query to run against copy data.
The select statement wont run on its own Main seems not to be recogniced.

Comment: What error do you get? The `DELETE` syntax is correct and valid in MS Access. For `SELECT ` statement add an asterisk `*` or any column, and try: `FROM History AS main`.